# Are there any ETW events created by IIS or ASP.NET which include the request URL?

Tags: asp.net, iis, trace, etw

I have been trying, without much success, to capture ETW events created by IIS or ASP.NET which include the request URL.

I am using Windows 8 (development) and Windows Server 2008 R2 (production), so IIS 8.0 and 7.5 respectively. I am aware that in IIS 8.5 there is [better ETW support](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/logging-to-etw-in-iis-85) but that's not going to help at the moment unfortunately.

Using *PerfView*, collecting system-wide events and with the following *Additional Providers* I get some events in the `Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Configuration` namespace but nothing that includes individual request details.

[image]

**Additional Providers**

```
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-APPHOSTSVC:*:5,Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Configuration:*:5,Microsoft-Windows-IIS-FTP:*:5,Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IisMetabaseAudit:*:5,Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IISReset:*:5,Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC:*:5,Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-PerfCounters:*:5 ,Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP:*:5,Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WMSVC:*:5
```

If I run `logman query providers` I get the following, so I know these providers are available (on my Windows 8 machine).

```
Provider                                 GUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Microsoft-Windows-IIS-APPHOSTSVC         {CAC10856-9223-48FE-96BA-2A772274FB53}
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Configuration      {DC0B8E51-4863-407A-BC3C-1B479B2978AC}
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-FTP                {AB29F35C-8531-42FF-810D-B8552D23BC92}
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IisMetabaseAudit   {BBB924B8-F415-4F57-AA45-1007F704C9B1}
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IISReset           {DA9A85BB-563D-40FB-A164-8E982EA6844B}
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC              {05448E22-93DE-4A7A-BBA5-92E27486A8BE}
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-PerfCounters {90303B54-419D-4081-A683-6DBCB532F261}
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP           {670080D9-742A-4187-8D16-41143D1290BD}
Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WMSVC              {23108B68-1B7E-43FA-94FB-EC3066805744}
```

I've also tried using logman to create an ETL file, but this doesn't seem to capture anything IIS related:

**etw.ps1**

```
logman start ASPTrace -pf providers.txt -ets
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
logman stop ASPTrace -ets
```

**providers.txt**

```
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-APPHOSTSVC" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Configuration" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-FTP" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IisMetabaseAudit" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IISReset" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-PerfCounters" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WMSVC" 0xFFFFFFFE 5
```

I have tried the above with `0xFFFFFFFE` and `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft-Windows-HttpService            {DD5EF90A-6398-47A4-AD34-4DCECDEF795F}

Look at the Deliver event. It has RequestUrl, and the app pool the request got forwarded to.

This is available in Windows Vista and higher.

Comment: The Deliver event? What specific parser can I use to parse httpservice events?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own [ETW provider class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/09/announcing-the-eventsource-nuget-package-write-to-the-windows-event-log.aspx) with [System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2013/08/10/the-eventsource-nuget-package-and-support-for-the-windows-event-log-channel-support.aspx) and log here the request url in your project if you need it.

[image]

You can now also use [WPT to capture the events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2013/08/10/wpr-wpa-support-for-viewing-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for something that can trace existing deployed applications without code changes - so was hoping there was something already being logged that I could hook into. Thanks for the tip about WPT though.

Comment: MS is adding more ETW logging with each new version. Maybe IIS 8.5 does have it. Try it in a VM.

Comment: Yep, there's some new stuff in IIS 8.5 - there's a link in the question.

Comment: does it log the request URL?

Comment: IIS 8.5 does - I'm trying to find out if there's a way of getting the request URL in IIS 8.0 though.

Comment: in this case your out of luck. Implement it on your own or update later to 2012 R2 to get IIS8.5.